# Error: ORA-02289 (2: 10): PL/SQL: ORA-02289

Tags: oracle, triggers, sequence

I am writing a Trigger for Toad. But I am facing an error like

```
"[Error] ORA-02289 (2: 10): PL/SQL: ORA-02289: sequence does not exist". 

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER ACTSINFO.USERMASTER_INSERT
BEFORE INSERT
ON ACTSINFO.USERMASTER
REFERENCING NEW AS New OLD AS Old
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  SELECT USERMASTER_ID_SEQ.NEXTVAL INTO :NEW.ID FROM dual;
END;
```

Can anyone help me? 
I am newcomer to toad.

Comment: Does the sequence `usermaster_id_seq` exist in the same schema that the trigger is in? There's also no point `referencing new as new`, you can just delete that entire line.

Comment: In addition to that having OLD in a BEFORE INSERT is vague, because you do not have any old row while performing insert.

Answer (score 8):

The Quest Software is only a tool. In thid case you have a precise error about what went wrong.  As the message says, a sequence called USERMASTER_ID_SEQ do not exist *in your schema*.

The solution might be adding the schema name (owner) before the name of sequence:

```
ACTSINFO.USERMASTER_ID_SEQ
```

You can find the owner with this query:

```
select sequence_owner 
from all_sequences
where sequence_name = 'USERMASTER_ID_SEQ';
```

If that does not help it means that you do not have rights to the sequence or it really does not exist.  So either you need to get the sequence's owner to grant SELECT on it to your user or you must create the sequence in the database.

To create a sequence you may want use the GUI of Toad. Or just use the PL/SQL statement

```
CREATE SEQUENCE ACTSINFO.USERMASTER_ID_SEQ
INCREMENT BY 1 
MAXVALUE 99999999999999999999 
MINVALUE 1 
CACHE 20 ;
```

Comment: Great that me answer was helpfull. If this close the question you should mark the answer as accepted. So the question will be answered.