# sequence does not exist

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate

While developing a web application using spring and hibernate i am getting the following execption.

java.sql.SQLException: ORA-02289: sequence does not exist

While i am trying to insert the data into a table i am usign sequence to increment the value of request_id.

I am using the following coding for inserting

```
    @Override
public void postRequest(RequestInfo requestInfo) 
{
Session session = null;
Transaction trans = null;
SessionFactory sessionFactory = null;

sessionFactory=HibernateConfig.getSessionFactory();
session= sessionFactory.openSession();
trans = session.beginTransaction();
session.save(requestInfo);
trans.commit();
session.close();

}
public class HibernateConfig 
{
public static SessionFactory sessionFactory;
public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() 
{
sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
return sessionFactory;
}
}
```

In hibernate mapping i have mentioned like this

```
<id name="requestId" type="int" column="request_id" >
<generator class="sequence">
<param name="sequence">REQUEST_INFO_SEQ</param>
</generator>
</id>
```

I tried with native also but i couldn't get the values to be get inserted.

i am using oracle 11g.

Can any one give me solution for this.

Comment: check if you are connecting to correct DB (if you have mutiple DB) and also check if the sequence is there in the DB for that table. there could be some Typo error

Comment: possible duplicate of [Error: ORA-02289 (2: 10): PL/SQL: ORA-02289](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9077897/error-ora-02289-2-10-pl-sql-ora-02289)

Answer (score 5):

The insert operation is working fine after giving the sequence name with the schema name like **schemaName.sequenceName** in the hbm.xml file.
Thank you all for responding the query.

Comment: I add the same problem with the annotations. I tried to use the attribute `schema` but without success... When I tried with `sequenceName=SCHEMA.SEQUENCENAME` everything went fine!

Comment: Thanks for the pointer..Eventually i added it as a synonym to access it without the schemaName qualifier.

Answer (score 2):

Does the sequence exist?  To check, do:

```
select * from all_sequences where sequence_name = 'REQUEST_INFO_SEQ'
```

Comment: Try to do it as **the same user** that your application is using. Might be a problem with the rights (grant select on the sequence)

Answer (score 0):

i think there is something wrong with the POJO object comming in parameter, you should create session first the do 3 things , making POJO object (transient state) then calling persistent methods save,update,delete(Persistent State) and trx.commit(Detached state of hibernate object). and should do this work in try catch block and catch HibernateException and then call finally which will close the session, and use buildSessionFactory();

sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();